# Key code printed on onPreviewKeyEvent callback

Tags: android-jetpack-compose

I'm so confused when in add onPreviewKeyEvent in my `OutlinedTextField`.

I am add desired key like it. `isAltPressed && it.key == Key.K` so K appended in `outlinedTextField` value.

```
OutlinedTextField(
value = x.value,
onValueChange = {x.value = it},
modifier = Modifier.onPreviewKeyEvent {
if (it.isAltPressed && it.key == Key.K) {
  println("key is pressed")
  true
} else {
  false
  }
 }
)
```

Comment: What is the issue?

Comment: issue is that  event key value added to the outlinedtextfield value

Comment: any one knows how to solve this type of problem